# What about \textthreequartersemdash in TU encoding?

Tags: fontspec, unicode

Is there an equivalent of `\textthreequartersemdash` in `TU` encoding? As far as I know, `\textthreequartersemdash` is provided by `textcomp` package and `TS1` encoding.

In `TS1` encoding, `\textthreequartersemdash` refers to `x2012` code-point. How to reach this code-point without `textcomp` package? I mean a construct like this:

```
\provide{\textthreequartersemdash}{...}
```

or

```
\ProvideTextCommandDefault{\textthreequartersemdash}{...}
```

Comment: why do you say x2012 is threequartersemdash? it is Figure dash which isn't necessarily .75em ? but if that is what you want you can use `^^^^2012` or `\symbol{"2012}` or just type  `‒` directly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `texrcomp.sty` declares `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textthreequartersemdash}{TS1}` and `ts1enc.def` says `\DeclareTextSymbol{\textthreequartersemdash}{TS1}{22}`.

Comment: yes that just says that the TS1 encoding has a three-quarter emdash in position 22.  My question was why you associate that with unicode position hex 2012 in your question? (as far as I can see, Unicode does not have a three-quarter-em dash character)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I gave wrong reference. Correct one: `xunicode.sty` says: `\DeclareUTFcharacter[\UTFencname]{x2012}{\textthreequartersemdash}`. But I;ve checked that the code point 2012 has same symbol as endash.

Comment: no, 2012 is a figure dash which is not necessarily the same as an emdash it just depends on the font designer. Presumably the authors of `xunicode` thought it better to use some dash for `\textthreequarterdash` but I'd disagree really, there is no need to give a standard definition as Unicode does not have the character. If you have an old document using this command then you have to decide per-docuemnt which dash to use instead (or to use a rule of length .75em rather than a character) there is no correct answer, it depends on the font, and on the person making the choice.